# Consulta por texto em tabela utilizando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Meu problema aparentemente simples tem me dados dores de cabeça. Tenho uma tabela que contem três colunas: `id`, `idpergunta`, `resposta`. Quando uma resposta é enviada para ser inserida nessa tabela eu verifico se a mesma já existe:

```
$where = [
            1 => $resposta['idpergunta'],
            2 => '' . $resposta['resposta'] . '',
        ];    

        return count($this->db->select("SELECT idresposta FROM resposta WHERE aberta = 1 AND idpergunta = ? AND resposta = ?", $where));
```

O método `select` é implementado utilizando PDO, da seguinte maneira:

```
public function select($sql, $array = array(), $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_OBJ, $class = '')
    {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_int($value)) {
                $stmt->bindValue("$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            } else {
                $stmt->bindValue("$key", $value);
            }
        }

        $stmt->execute();

        if ($fetchMode === PDO::FETCH_CLASS) {
            return $stmt->fetchAll($fetchMode, $class);
        } else {
            return $stmt->fetchAll($fetchMode);
        }
    }
```

No entanto, da maneira como está, se o texto da resposta for maior que duas palavras ele não o encontra. As vezes funciona e as vezes não. Já tentei de diversas maneiras, mas nada resolve. Hora funciona, hora não funciona. O que pode está causando isso? Eu tenho certeza absoluta que os dados estão corretos. Se eu fizer uma consulta manualmente no servidor o retorno acontece normalmente.

Comment: Como você tem três colunas e na `query` tem colunas como `idresposta` e aberta? Sendo que não tem na descrição que você deu da tabela. Testei aqui e não vi erro nenhum, testei pegando todas colunas, sem o `aberta` e com registros de 2, 3, 4 e 5 palavras, talvez o erro esteja aí, mas como não temos o código da tabela não da pra saber. Dá uma olhada nessa que fiz: http://github.com/Leonardo-Souza/MinPDO

Comment: Só esqueci de mencionar a coluna 'aberta' é um inteiro que tem valor 0 ou 1. Somente.